# Executing a plan

Tags: meaning, phrases, expressions

To execute a plan is to carry it out. However, isn't this wording strange? Why doesn't executing a plan mean the same thing as shooting it down?

Comment: Executives at companies take on a whole new meaning...

Answer (score 7):

*Execute* meaning "carry out" is actually the original meaning. *Execute* meaning "kill" comes from phrases along the lines of "execute [=carry out] a sentence of death". (Source: [etymonline.com](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=execution) (and [again](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=execute)).) Both are still in common use, and you should feel comfortable using the "carry out" sense without fear anyone will think you mean "kill" (in most contexts).

Comment: Indeed, *execute* in the sense 'to carry out' is very common in connection with sports (‘They executed that play perfectly’, etc.), which definitely qualifies as popular usage.